# If I buy options, ought I care Management Fee and Expense Ratios?

Tags: options

If at least two ETFs track same or similar index, and I buy just options on them, care if they have different [MERs](https://www.investopedia.com/articles/investing/062113/mutual-funds-management-fees-vs-mer.asp)? Ought I buy one with less MER?

I live Toronto.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you  care about an ETF's management fees, when buying options it's probably so far down the list of concerns that it's effectively not important because the fee difference is so diluted by the other pricing factors.  For example, if the fee difference is 1%, that's over the course of a year.  Most option plays are for a much shorter time period so the effect is far less.  Then reduce that further by the delta of the option and you're probably talking about pennies.

Of much greater importance is that the options that you are trading  are liquid with narrow bid/ask spreads so that your slippage costs are less and you can easily unwind your position.  And most importantly, you have to get the direction right since long options is a directional play.

Answer (score 1):

I would say no, in the same sense that you probably don't care about the landscaping expense of a company that you're trading stock options on. It's an expense that you'd consider when looking at the profitability of the company, but those factors are already considered in option prices.

MER is just another factor that affects the price of the underlying security - in this case, an ETF. Buying options on an ETF with high MER is no better or worse than on one with a low MER. It's just a factor that is baked into the underlying price and thus the price of options on it.

As Bob said, volatility and liquidity are much bigger factors in buying options.